# Move files older than x minutes

Tags: vbscript

I want the script to move all files (all file extensions `*.*`) older than  5 minutes from an INN folder to and ERROR folder. In my example `C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\` to `C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\Error`

So I figured how to *move files* and how to *find files older than x-time* after looking it up. Howover, putting this together is the issue for me.  Does anyone know how I can nail this?

This is what I got so far...

```
Dim age_threshold
age_threshold = 5
Dim folder_path
folder_path = WScript.Arguments(0)
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.getFolder(folder_path)
Dim old_file_not_found
old_file_found = 0
For Each file in f.Files
  Dim age
  age = DateDiff("n", file.DateLastModified, Now)
  If age > age_threshold Then
    old_file_found = 1
    .MoveFile "C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\*.*", "C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\Error"
    Exit for
  end if
Next
WScript.Quit
```

I'm used to batch, so this is a little bit greek to me (source http://www.evalesco.com/check-any-file-older-x-minutes-directory).

Now where do I set (dim?) my INN and ERROR folder in this script? And I'm pretty sure the `if age` followed by `.movefile` is wrong, so I probably need a little correction there.

[image: error_running_script]

**Update** Whats missing in the image is a backslash after error (`\error\`) in the `move.file` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call methods without an object providing the method, so `.MoveFile` should be `fso.MoveFile`. However, in its current form the script would move all files from `C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn` if any of the files in the folder passed as argument to the script is older than 5 minutes.

What you need to do is pass `C:\test\inn` as the argument to the script, and move only those files that actually are older:

```
If age > age_threshold Then
  file.Move "C:\test\inn\error\"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, due to my inexperience, I am having some issues. I guess I need to dim my INN folder somewhere. Would that be here? `Set f = fso.getFolder("C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn")` - and the f.move, should I add both the inn and error folder to that line? Like this `f.move "C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\" "C:\CopyFlow\Directory test\Inn\Error"`

Comment: If you don't want to pass the folder as an argument to the script you can define it like that, yes. The `Move` method should be called for each file as in my (updated) sample code above.

Comment: Great thanks, that makes sence. I think it should be almost complete now, but I'm having a small issue running the file to test if it works. "Expected ending on the sentence" (directly translatet). I've tried "exit for" and "end if", but could it be more I'm missing? Its refering to the string with file.move in it.

Comment: Syntax errors like "expected end of statement" require seeing the actual code. Add the code you currently have as well as the exact error message to your question.

Comment: Wasnt sure how to share it, so I added the image here of the error https://unsee.cc/sunezabo/ - should be viewable for an hour. Hopefully it'll do. (Obs, noticed the image cuts the edge a bit. The only text outside should be _\error"_ )

Comment: I get that, my bad. Refresh to see image.

Comment: Do you see a second argument to `file.Move` in my answer? If not, why did you add one in your code?

Comment: @Excessium When using [`file.Move()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxtftw67(v=vs.84).aspx) you already have the `File` object so it knows it's current location you only need that when using [`MoveFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6(v=vs.84).aspx) at the `FileSystemObject` object level.

Comment: Alright, thanks @Lankymart - guess I didn't fully understand file.move vs movefile. Thanks for clearing that up for me. :) Ajusted my script now. Wiechers, my bad. Tried a couple of things because I was still getting the error. However, it was a small mistake by me. I forgot a backslash (even tho you mentioned it in your example), so its alright now. Accepted your answer. Thanks yet again!